# Inequality over positive integers

Tags: inequality, integers

Let $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$ and $y_1, y_2,\dots, y_n$ be two sets of positive integers such that $$x_i<y_i  \quad \text{for all } i$$ and $$x_iy_i \leq x_{i+1}y_{i+1} \quad \text{for all } i$$ I am studying when the inequality $$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\left(y_i - \sqrt{x_ny_n}\right)\geq 0$$ holds.

It is clear that if $y_i\geq \sqrt{x_ny_n} \quad \text{for all } i$ then the inequality holds. Can we prove something stronger, like "if $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n y_i}{n} \geq \sqrt{x_ny_n}$ then the inequality holds"? Or some other condition of this type.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since $x_i < y_i$ and $x_i y_i < x_{i+1} y_{i+1}$, we can write $y_i > x_i$ and $x_{i+1}y_{i+1} > x_i y_i$, which implies that
\begin{align}
y_{i+1}^2 &= y_{i+1}y_{i+1} \\
&> x_{i+1}y_{i+1} \\
&> x_i y_i \\
&> x_ix_i \\
&= x_i^2
\end{align}
for all $i= 1, \ldots, n$. So we have
\begin{align}
& \ \ \  \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \left( y_i - \sqrt{x_n y_n} \right) \\ 
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \left( x_i y_i - x_i \sqrt{x_n y_n } \right) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i - \sqrt{x_n y_n }  \sum_{i=1}^n  x_i \\ 
&\geq n x_1 y_1 - \sqrt{x_n y_n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \\
&> n x_1^2 - \sqrt{y_n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \\
&=  n x_1^2 - y_n \sum_{i=1}^n x_i. 
\end{align}
Thus if
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \leq \frac{n x_1^2}{y_n}, 
$$
then we have
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \left( y_i - \sqrt{x_n y_n} \right)  \geq 0.
$$

Comment: thanks for your answer! I like the sufficient condition for the inequality to hold that you have proved.

Comment: Noting that $y_1 \geq x_1 + 1$ strengthens your condition a bit. If we have $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \leq \frac{n x_1^2 +nx_1}{y_n}$ then the inequality holds.